# Bounding a probability

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

I am trying to prove a limit theorem. In one of the steps, it is written that, setting
$$\Delta_n=\frac{V_1+...+V_r}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}-\frac{W_1+...+W_r}{\sigma\sqrt{n}},$$
where $V_1, ..., V_r$ are not independent random variables, but $W_1, ..., W_r$ are (I don't know if this fact is even used), then
$$P(|\Delta_n| > \varepsilon) \leq \sum_{j=1}^r P\left(|V_j-W_j|>\frac{\varepsilon \sigma \sqrt{n}}{r}  \right).$$

I am not being able to prove this inequality, and I feel like I am missing something really obvious. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hint: $$[|X_1+\cdots+X_r|>x]\subseteq\bigcup_{k=1}^r[|X_k|>x/r]$$ hence $$P(|X_1+\cdots+X_r|>x)\leqslant\sum_{k=1}^nP(|X_k|>x/r)$$

Comment: Don't the sets $\{|X_k|>x/r\}$ have to be disjoint for me to conclude that the probability of the union is the sum of the probabilities?

Comment: One does not need "to conclude that the probability of the union is the sum of the probabilities", only that the probability of the union is **at most** the sum of the probabilities.